# Postgresql query by year

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query the Postgres table by only Year

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE date_part('year', date) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE);
```

when I pass the CURRENT_DATE it is working, but when I pass the '2019', It is not working.

how to do the same using flask-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date_part function returns integer - not string.
This should work:
`SELECT * FROM events WHERE date_part('year', date) = 2019;`

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: how to do this in flask sql alchemy

Comment: You should create a new question regarding flask and include relevant code you are working with and what you need help specificly with.